# Creating 2 indexes for a join table

Tags: sql, database-design, indexing

Suppose I have many-to-many relationship between "contributors" and "pages". I have a join table with 2 columns: `contributor_id` and `page_id`. Through my application, I'll often want to:

a) For a given contributor, find its pages
b) For a given page, find its contributors

I know that creating a (two) multi-column index would work here, but in what order should the index be? Should I maybe create 2 multi-column indexes, one where `contributor_id` goes first and the other where `page_id` goes first?

Comment: Learn to tag questions with the software you are actually using.  I replaced the extraneous database tags with just "sql".

Comment: The cost and the benefit of doing this depend on your DBMS and on the version of it as well.  Without that info, it's just speculation.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, creating two indexes makes sense in your situation.

First on `(contributor_id, page_id)`, second on `(page_id, contributor_id)`.

Also, most likely both of them should be unique.

Comment: How about index merge? Possibly it would have similar performance and little storage overhead, whereas two double-field indexes "weigh more".  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/index-merge-optimization.html

Comment: @Kleskowy, I don't see how the index merge feature of the query processor can help here. If you have, say, one index on `(contributor_id, page_id)` only and want to search `SELECT contributor_id WHERE page_id=123`, then this index would not help at all. So, if it is common to have queries `SELECT contributor_id WHERE page_id=123` and `SELECT page_id WHERE contributor_id=321`, then it makes sense to have two indexes.

Comment: This is what I meant - two _single-column_ indexes (smaller) with possible index_merge VS two _double-column_ (larger) indexes. It's just an idea.

Comment: @Kleskowy, Let's look at `SELECT contributor_id WHERE page_id=123`. If you have a single-column index on `page_id` it will help to quickly find row(s) that satisfy the criteria, but then for each found row the engine will have to do a lookup of the column that is not part of the index (`contributor_id`). If you have a second single-column index on `contributor_id` it will **not** help to eliminate this lookup. But, if there is an index on `(page_id, contributor_id)`, then engine can read values of both columns directly from index, which is more efficient.